# Finding Countries that the capital have the countries name in it

Tags: sql

How can I find the countries where the capital name includes the name of the country.

ex:

```
Country   Capital
--------------------
A         Acity
B         B
C         xxx
D         capital of D
```

The answer would return `A,B` and `D`

I have tried this, but is only returning country `B`

```
SELECT name, capital
  FROM world
 WHERE name LIKE capital
```

This question is the thirteenth question from
[Sqlzoo](http://sqlzoo.net/wiki/SELECT_names)

Answer (score 12):

You need to use it's correct concatenation syntax.

```
SELECT name, capital
  FROM world
 WHERE capital LIKE concat('%',name,'%')
```

Note the below query is correct for most DBMS

```
SELECT name, capital
FROM world
WHERE name LIKE '%' + capital + '%'
```

But ill raise an error at [Sqlzoo](http://sqlzoo.net/wiki/SELECT_names)

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '+ capital + '%'' at line 3

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT capital, name FROM world WHERE capital LIKE CONCAT('%', name, '%');
```

It is the correct answer. I have checked it

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT name, capital
FROM world
WHERE name LIKE '%' + capital + '%'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try wild card compare:

```
SELECT name, capital
  FROM world
 WHERE name LIKE '%' + capital + '%'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT name, capital
FROM world
WHERE name LIKE CONCAT('%', capital, '%');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT name
 FROM world
 WHERE name = capital
```

The equal sign is used as both an assignment operator in certain contexts, and as a comparison operator. 
the `=` assignment operator cannot be used in all contexts, and is only valid as part of a `SET` statement, or the `SET` clause of an `UPDATE` statement.

Answer (score 0):

On https://sqlzoo.net/wiki/SELECT_names the correct answer would be:

```
SELECT name
FROM world 
WHERE name LIKE capital;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT name FROM world WHERE capital LIKE name;
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

I am also doing that question now, only the following answer is accepted by te SQL Zoo's system.

```
SELECT capital, name
FROM world
WHERE capital LIKE CONCAT(name, '%');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT capital, name
  FROM world
 WHERE capital LIKE (concat('%', name, '%'))
```

- like: to search about the pattern
- concat: to create the pattern you
  need

Answer (score 0):

**This is for countries which have capital name in their name.**

```
SELECT name
FROM world
WHERE capital LIKE CONCAT('%', name, '%');
```

**The below is for countries that have same name as capital**

```
SELECT name
FROM world
WHERE capital LIKE name;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT name
  FROM world
 WHERE name LIKE Capital
```